# How to fill property in List<object> that has annotation [SQLite.Ignore]

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have entity `Item`, out of which is made SQLite table `Item` and entity/table `ItemRelations` which is the M side of table Item. I take record from table ItemRelations and join it's Order property to entity Item on the same named property with sql query (described below)

```
[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
   [Column("code")]
   [Unique]
   public string Code {get;set;}   

   public string Name {get;set;}

   [SQLite.Ignore]
   Public string Order {get;set;}
}

[Table("item_relations")]
public class ItemRelations
{
   [Unique]
   public string Code{get;set;}
   [Unique]
   public string ItemCode {get;set;}
   public string Order{get;set;}
}
```

When I make ***List*** or ***ObservableCollection*** out of this item and do some join in sql, property *Order* is empty while *SQLite.Ignore* exists and if I remove *Ignore* it's filled like it should be. Inplementation in code

```
public List<item> GetItems()
{
    string sqlQuery = "select B.order as Order, * from item A 
                       left join item_relations B on B.ItemCode = A.code ";
    return db.DefferedQuery<Item>(sqlQuery).ToList();
}
```

For each element in result list GetItems(), Order = " ". How to fill this property value in *List*? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to remove that attribute. Why is it there in the first place?

Comment: @nvoigt - I do not want this property to exists in table.

Comment: uh... ok... then why have it? If you don't want it filled from your database, then it will be empty. Maybe your question needs more context, can you post a MCVE of what you want to do?

Comment: @nvoigt - I fill List with sql query using join left command, so this property has conditional value and is used just for presenting linked property value from another table.

Comment: Again... post it all, we are pretty bad at guessing what you might have done. Have a look at [mcve] and write one of those.